# Not enter data in mysql database with wordpress and php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Im trying to add a new user name to mysql table throw wordpress. But everytime I try to do it, I have no error message, but there are no lines added to the data base.

This is the wordpress page with the php inside:

```
<table>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<strong>Please enter your information in order to download the Macs Cabs     
App</strong>
<tr><td>
Name:</td><td><input name="Name" type="text" id="sName"></td></tr>
Email Address:</td><td><input name="Email" type="text" id="sEmail"></td>   </tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</form></table>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
{
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("foundint_Sababa", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO `Users` (`sName`, `sEmail`)  
VALUES    ('{$_POST['sName']}','{$_POST['sEmail']}')";


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

$info = mysql_info(); echo $info;

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I can't see whats wrong. I think it may be something wrong with the connection. Any ideas?

Thank you!

**Edit**

As suggested, Im trying to use `$wpdb` so I've created a php file in a folder call my-codes (at the same level of wp-admin, wp-content and wp-includes) and I added the following code to a file call insertUser.php:

```
<?php       
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert("wp_submitted_form", array(
"sName" => $sName,
"sEmail" => $sEmail));
?>
```

Now in my page Im trying to call this function and Im doing this:

```
<table>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<strong>Please enter your information in order to download the Macs Cabs     
App</strong>
<tr><td>
Name:</td><td><input name="Name" type="text" id="sName"></td></tr>
Email Address:</td><td><input name="Email" type="text" id="sEmail"></td>       </tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</form></table>
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
   {
     include("./my-codes/insertUsers.php");
   } 
?>
```

And im still not being able to insert any row in the database. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I needed a pluggin to actually connect my sql database with wordpress. The code is correct.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: How is this a wordpress page? There are no wordpress functions in it...

Comment: You should be using `$wpdb` to make database queries in Wordpress

Comment: Should I addthe `$wpdb` inside the page?

Comment: Yes you have to add `gobal $wpdb;` at the top of the page

Comment: And in insertUser.php: connect your (i.e) include **wp-config.php** file at the top otherwise it will not be connected to Database..

Comment: You will not get any error on submission but you data will not be getting inserted. The major error is that you have not connected the database file in wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with the code that i have provided.

```
    <table>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <strong>Please enter your information in order to download the Macs Cabs     
    App</strong>
    <tr><td>
    Name:</td><td><input name="Name" type="text" id="sName"></td></tr>
    Email Address:</td><td><input name="Email" type="text" id="sEmail"></td>   </tr>
    <tr><td>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
    </form></table>

    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root"); // ensure that your password in empty or root in your localhost
    if (!$con)
    {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("foundint_Sababa", $con);

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
       // Previous Insert Query which has discrepency in form input names and Insert Values 
      //$sql="INSERT INTO `Users` (`sName`, `sEmail`) VALUES ('{$_POST['sName']}','{$_POST['sEmail']}')";

      // My new Query with corrected form input names for Input Values during POST.
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `Users`(`sName`, `sEmail`) VALUES ('".$_POST['Name']."','".$_POST['Email']."')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "1 record added";
        $info = mysql_info(); echo $info;
        mysql_close($con);
    }
```

Finally have a check at the table field Names and my code works fine hope it will serve you to.

Comment: The answer would be even more helpful if you pointed out what the actual problem was (discrepancy between the form field names and the used variable names), in the current state everybody has to compare it to the original code line per line to find the differences.

Comment: The difference was `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` but is still not working. I think there is a problem with the connection to the database. There is anything that Im missing in the connection maybe?

Comment: Ensure that your localhost has password for connection.  Mostly it will be empty

Comment: But you have mentioned it has root

Comment: The credentials are ok, I tryed out of wordpress and it works fine

Comment: Oops!!. Rock on. Welcome :)

Comment: Hope so you can mark this question as complete if you have got the output.

Comment: I haven´t. I still can´t get the information stored in the db

Comment: The problem is when Im doing it through this code, in the wordpress page that Im not beng able to add that information

Comment: Yes using wordpress you can't connect your database like this right. You will configure all in the wp-config.php file and you have to just include in this page.

Comment: And you have to change the codes a bit inorder to insert. You no need to give the `$con` while executing the query.

Comment: While using it in wordpress it is better to use Wp Query for Inserting into database and Selecting from database like that. Don't prefer this mysql way sine it may not be working in some server too..

Comment: You should not use this code. It is voulnerable, because the post data is inserted directly into the query. This is delicate for sql injections. As mentioned by others you should not use mysql_* functions anymore. They are deprecated. Use wordpress' own WP Query object for you concerns.

Comment: @SomeAnonymousPerson your last edit changed your question so much that the answers became absolutely useless. You shouldn't change your question completely, especially when you start to use a completely different approach. You should ask a new question in such a case (you can link to the old one for context).

Comment: And you are still making the same mistake you did in the first place, using the wrong input attribute as variable names.

Answer (score 1):

use the query like this one to make thing happen,

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `Users` (`sName`, `sEmail`) VALUES ('".$_POST['sName']."','".$_POST['sEmail']."')";
```

for preventing from injection you can use this way to build query.

```
$name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `Users` (`sName`, `sEmail`) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
```

using prepared statement

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$name=addslashes($_POST['sName']);
$email=addslashes($_POST['sEmail']);

$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `Users` (`sName`, `sEmail`) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $name,$email);
$stmt->execute();
```

for detailed on prepared statement got to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: What about sql injections? This query is highly voulnerable.

Comment: you can use the many ways to stop the sql injection.
You Can use default sql escape function like htmlescape character or using the prepared statement for preventing from sql injection.@Marcel

Comment: Check onto the input value names that you have used @DhavalPurohit make a change of it then it makes a sense if he copies and tries your codes. But in Wordpress the use of WP Queries is advisable not the mysql or prepared statements.

Comment: ohk then why don't you use it in your code ? @NareshKumar.P